# Win32 COM object consumed in a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delphi, winapi, com

We have a Win32 COM object developed in Delphi XE. From our test program developed in Delphi we're able to start the COM object in a thread. When debugging we can see that the running COM object is inside the thread created by the calling routine.

In our C# application, which is a service developed using the same recipe for the thread execution as done in our Delphi test application, we don't see the same behaviour. The COM object doesn't run inside the C# thread that executes it. We've used Kernel32.dll's `GetCurrentThreadID()` to get the Windows handle. When watching the Windows thread handle from our COM object, it is always the same handle. It's not the executing thread's handle.

Is it possible to run a COM object inside a C# thread and have it live inside the thread? Basically, how do we get the same Windows thread handler from the C# thread in the COM object?

Our C# thread is MTA.

/Brian

Comment: What is the threading model for COM DLL?

Comment: Your C# thread is MTA, but what about the supported threading model of the COM coclass? It is entirely possible it is *not* MTA-supported and as such the RPC manager is starting a separate thread to service (and own) it forever, marshaling calls from your MTA to that STA and back.

Comment: Hi. Our Delphi COM Object is ciMultiInstance and tmApartment.

Comment: That would explain the separate STA holding your object, for pretty much the exact reason I specified above. And therefore to answer your question, no, you're not going to create that object in your MTA. It doesn't support it. You *can* get it inside an STA thread from C# if it is possible to create one (I'm a C# idiot so I honestly have no idea if this is possible).

Comment: Hi WhozCraig. Thanks for your input. STA is possible i C#. But isn't my COM object MTA (Multi Threaded Appartment)? The COM is MultiInstance and Appartment? Isn't that more equvelant to MTA than it is to STA?

Comment: `tmApartment` is STA (`COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`), `tmFree` or `tmBoth` is MTA (`COINIT_MULTITHREADED`): see [Managed and Unmanaged threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s8ee185%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi. Thanks to all of you (o; An STA thread is working and doing it's job. I'll read up on Managed and Unmanaged thread. Thanks to your all!

Comment: "Multi-instance" has nothing to do with the threading model. "Apartment" is the same as STA.